# Interpreting the geom_way in the table created using osm2po

Tags: qgis, postgresql, pgrouting, osm2po

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Issues while plotting the results of pgRouting shortest path](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26484/issues-while-plotting-the-results-of-pgrouting-shortest-path)

I am trying to actually figure out what this column exactly represents and how to use that in my case. I created a network topology and persisted it to postgresql database using `osm2po` tool for a certain region. Now I am using pgrouting on it to find the shortest route. I am not sure how this column is used by qgis to display the route. It's just a bunch of number, how can I use it in my case?

I am actually using gpx format file to transfer the shortest path. How can I exploit this geometry and send that information in gpx so that it is displayed nicely.

Comment: Please don't open another thread with the same topic.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should check out user @underdark instruction on her site. there is some information about using it in qgis.

- Osm2po Part 2 – PgRouting on OSM the Easy Way, [here](http://underdark.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/osm2po-part-2-pgrouting-on-osm-the-easy-way/).
- A First Glimpse at pgRouting Layer for QGIS, [here](http://underdark.wordpress.com/2011/11/24/a-first-glimpse-at-pgrouting-layer-for-qgis/).
- A Beginner’s Guide to pgRouting, [here](http://underdark.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/a-beginners-guide-to-pgrouting/).

i hope it helps you...